# How can I print out or copy merge fields?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, mail-merge

I have very complicated mergefields in Word 2010, thus I would like to print out what I coded already to analyze it.

However, I cannot copy and paste the pure code, because it always converts to output. I neither found any option to print out the mergefields - NOT the result, but the original fields.

Example of code that I want to print or copy:
`{ IF { MERGESEQ } = 1 "x" "y"}`

How to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose this option will make the difference:

Go to `File > Options` and scroll down:

[image: Field codes]

With checkbox active, I get field codes "printed" to PDF output.

Answer (score 1):

For Word 2010

Go to FILE > Options > Advanced
scroll down to the header title "Print"
Click or check the box that reads "Print fields codes instead of their values"

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Tools > Options and click the Print tab. Under "Include with print" select Field codes. For more info see here:

http://www.ehow.com/how_2265273_print-field-codes-word.html

Comment: There is no Tools > Options in Word 2010, and basically you repeated what the other answer already mentioned hours ago, but yours is for an older version of Word.